# Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, di

Работаю с Ioc Autofac. Не могу понять что происходит в данном отрывке кода

```
private ISettingService _settings;

public ImportSettings(ISettingService settings)
{
    _settings = settings;
}
```

Я создаю поле и затем в конструкторе делаю непонятные для меня вещи.

Что тут происходит?

Comment: а что непонятного в присваивании полю значения полученного параметра?

Comment: в конструкторе мы полю _settings присваиваем значение параметра settings, а откуда получает значение поле settings?

Comment: https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/22104901/

Comment: _а откуда получает значение поле settings?_ - это не поле, а **параметр**, и как ни странно он передается при вызове данного конструктора :-)

Comment: Ответ на ваши все вопросы я дал ниже.

Comment: @АлександрПузанов, подозреваю, автор хотел узнать как именно Autofac вызывает этот конструктор и передает в него параметр

Comment: Да уж... ))) Тогда ничем не помогу

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Этот фрагмент кода никак не связан с Autofac.
Здесь показано приватное поле `_settings`, которое инициализируется в конструкторе `ImportSettings`, указанном ниже, передаваемым в него параметром `settings`.

Answer (score -1):

Когда будете создавать экземпляр класса, то при вызове пользовательского конструктора ImportSettings() закрытому полю _settings будет присвоено значение по умолчанию. Значение по умолчанию берется из параметра settings.

Comment: Эээ, а что означает в вашем ответе «по умолчанию»?

Comment: А в чем задача конструктора? Передать ссылку на экземпляр класса и присвоить полям значения по умолчанию.

Comment: Ну, в C# «значение по умолчанию» означает обычно параметры метода, которые можно не указывать: `public ImportSettings(ISettingService settings = null)`, здесь `null` значение по умолчанию.

Comment: При вызове конструктора можно указать значение отличное от NULL. Это уже не будет считаться значением по умолчанию?

Comment: под значением по умолчанию еще понимают `default(T)`